# Ordering by a selected column from database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I have the following table that is meant to show a win/loss record and to have rankings. I'm running into two issues with it though.

- First issue is that my rank `<td>` is not progressing like I want it to. What I mean by that is for each record that is looped and output, I want it to be numbered for.

i.e.:

1

2

3, etc.

- The second part I cannot figure out is I want the person with the highest win total to be ranked the highest. I also want losses to be configured into that. So if someone is 5-0, their rank will be higher than someone's that is 5-1.

Could someone point me in the right direction with these issues I am running into?

```
  <h2>Division 1</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Wins</th>
                    <th>Losses</th>
                </tr>
<?php
try {
    //Prepare
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE `division`=1")) {

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ranking_id, $ranking_user_id, $ranking_firstname, $ranking_username, $ranking_division, $ranking_wins, $ranking_losses); 

        //var_dump($stmt);

        if (!$stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }

    $stmt->store_result();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $ranking_firstname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ranking_wins; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ranking_losses; ?></td>
        </table>
<?php       
        }
        }   else {
            echo "<p>There aren't any players in division 1 yet.</p>";
            }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ORDER BY` like this

Do this:

```
SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE `division`=1" ORDER BY Wins DESC, Losses
```

More: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

For your first question you `</table>` needs to be out of your php `while` loop. Also have a counter which you can increment and show the order.

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><php echo $count; $count++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ranking_firstname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ranking_wins; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ranking_losses; ?></td>
    </tr>      
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Something better? Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Rereading question I think it should be _SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE `division`=1" ORDER BY Wins DESC, Losses_        (to give 5-0, 5-1 ...)

Comment: @PaulF Chris Thanks for the catch guys. Answer updated.

Comment: I get an error for this line `int $count = 0;`.....`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$count' (T_VARIABLE)`. Why would a foreach be better?

Comment: Remove the `int` before `$count` foreach doesn't require a `$count` to be initialized which we have to in a while loop

Comment: Gotcha. I changed the count variable to equal 1, so that 0 doesn't show up, but everything works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The numbering issue can be resolved as such:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ranking_firstname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ranking_wins; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ranking_losses; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php       
    $i++;
}
```

This sets a variable `$i` to '1' (outside the loop), echos the variable as the number in your `<td>`, and increments the variable `$i++` before the loop is closed.

Oh yeah, and don't close your `<table>` inside the loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the [`ORDER BY` clause](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-clause.htm) in your query. It can sort by a column directly or by some calculation. For example, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM team_rankings
WHERE division = 1
ORDER BY
    (wins - losses) DESC,
    wins DESC
```

This way 1-0 would be ranked higher than 6-6 but lower than 2-1. How appropriate this is is up to you to decide.